# How do I decode unicode characters via python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to import the following json file using python:

The file is called `new_json.json`:

`{
    "nextForwardToken": "f/3208873243596875673623625618474139659",
    "events": [
        {
            "ingestionTime": 1045619,
            "timestamp": 1909000,
            "message": "2 32823453119 eni-889995t1 54.25.64.23 156.43.12.120 3389 23 6 342 24908 143234809 983246 ACCEPT OK"
        }]
}`

I have the following code to read the json file, and remove the unicode characters:

```
JSON_FILE = "new_json.json"
with open(JSON_FILE) as infile:
    print infile
    print '\n type of infile is \n', infile
    data = json.load(infile)
    str_data = str(data)  # convert to string to remove unicode characters
    wo_unicode = str_data.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore')
    print 'unicode characters have been removed \n'
    print wo_unicode
```

But `print wo_unicode` still prints with the unicode characters (i.e.`u`) in it.

The unicode characters cause a problem when trying to treat the json as a dictionary:

```
for item in data:
    iden = item.get['nextForwardToken']
```

...results in an error:

`AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'`

This has to work in Python2.7. Is there an easy way around this?

Comment: what problem is the unicode causing?

Comment: *"How to remove unicode characters in json file via python?"* Make the file completely empty, that's the only way. (Hint: **All** characters are Unicode characters, including, say `a` and `q`.)

Comment: The question might be better rephrased as 'How do I decode unicode' - and the answer may well be dependent on such as current code page in the cmd shell on windows (if you're running this on that "OS").

Comment: `json.load()` gives you a dict, everything you do with that dict has nothing to do with JSON any more, as the dict could come from anywhere. Now, what is unclear to me is why you even try to convert the dict to a string and what you want to achieve with that.

Comment: Question has been updated to address both comments. Thanks.

Comment: When you say "remove the unicode characters" and give "u" as example, do you perhaps refer to "u" as prefix to string literals like `s = u'abc'` in Python2? BTW: Upgrade to Python3!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I converted the dictionary to a string in order to remove the `u` characters.  `decode` only operates on strings.  Dictionary keys are not mutable, so I can't modify those.

Comment: I think you need to take a step back. You are trying various solutions to a (yet unnamed) problem that each make no sense at all. Instead of that, rather write a new question where you describe what problem you are actually trying to solve instead of how to implement the flawed approach you are pursuing.

Comment: I don't see any unusual characters in your posted file.

Comment: Sorry for  overlooking this.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with unicode, you are trying to treat the keys as dicts, just use `data`  to get `'nextForwardToken'`:

```
print data.get('nextForwardToken')
```

When you iterate over `data`, you are iterating over the keys so `'nextForwardToken'.get('nextForwardToken')`, `"events".get('nextForwardToken')` etc.. are obviously not going to work even with the correct syntax.

Whether you access by `data.get(u'nextForwardToken')` or `data.get('nextForwardToken')`, both will return the value for the key:

```
In [9]: 'nextForwardToken' == u'nextForwardToken'
Out[9]: True
In [10]: data[u'nextForwardToken']
Out[10]: u'f/3208873243596875673623625618474139659'   
In [11]: data['nextForwardToken']
Out[11]: u'f/3208873243596875673623625618474139659'
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you the values as str without the unicode

```
import json
JSON_FILE = "/tmp/json.json"
with open(JSON_FILE) as infile:
    print infile
    print '\n type of infile is \n', infile
    data = json.load(infile)
    print data
    str_data = json.dumps(data)
    print str_data
```